# CakePHP - How to manipulate the request data in a component?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my component methods, how can I get the request data that is normally read by the controller?

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

    public function processData() {

        // Get the data normally found in $this->request->data

    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are 2 ways to do this, second way is simpler:

Add this in your component

```
public function initialize(Controller $controller) {
    $this->controller = $controller;
}
```

You can then access the request data in the component by doing:

```
$this->controller->request->data
```

Or alternatively, you could just pass it through to your function.
E.g.

```
public function processData($data) {

}
```

And then call it with

```
$this->MyComponent->processData($this->request->data);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first method already but did it with `startup()` and it didn't work.  Not sure if that method was deprecated in Cake 2.0

Comment: Maybe they changed it, this page has the up to date details: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html

Comment: Actually both are valid, initialize runs before the controllers beforeFilter method and startup runs after it